# Hi everyone, I can't run fortran code with "Script" or "Atom runner". How can I run fortran on ATOM?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, text-editor

I have installed two packages related with the language, "ide-fortran" and "language-fortran".  Is there another runner that I can try? Or maybe is there something else I am forgeting to do?
I have already installed gfortran and python in my system too, I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: What is the extension of your file name?  I just updated my atom packages and tried a code with extension .f90. When i selected the script option in packages the fortran code ran to completion.

Comment: It works! Thank's a lot bro! I wrote the extension .f90 and then the code ran well.

Comment: glad i could help