# Running Fortran via Atom

Tags: eclipse, fortran, atom-editor, gfortran

1)I installed Atom. But cannot see a run button despite I entered the code(excercise.f95).
2)I ran the code in Eclipse. But I do not know how to rerun it from the saved file.

I am still learning basic Fortran and I installed everything by myself.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to see how to use this site - like why not ask a new question in an answer. Please use [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions.

Comment: You need a Fortran compiler to compile the code. Then you can run the result of the compilation (for example an .exe file). Do you have a Fortran compiler? Which one? Do you know how to run it?

Comment: Atom, by default, does not run _any_ code. You will need to install a [third-party package](https://atom.io/packages/) to do so.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311315/hi-everyone-i-cant-run-fortran-code-with-script-or-atom-runner-how-can-i

Comment: I have installed gfortran as the Fortran compiler. Interms of thrid-party-packages, I have installed Script and Language-fortran. After importing the following code and pressing "command + i", it showed "What's your name? " at the bottom of the screen.  But it didn't allow me to put the name.      program Fortrantut_1
          implicit none
            character*20 :: name
            character(len = 20) ::f_name, l_name
            print*, "What's your name? " 
            read*, f_name, l_name
            print*, "Hello ", " ", f_name, " ", l_name
      end program Fortrantut_1

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Do not put important information into comments, it just becomes lost here. you can also provide a screenshot.